# Message type websocket gdax (coinbase)

Tags: python, websocket, coinbase-api

I am interested in getting real-time data using the Gdax (Coinbase) WebSocket. I'm a total noob so I am inspecting the example Gdax posted in their documentation:

```
import gdax, time
class myWebsocketClient(gdax.WebsocketClient):
    def on_open(self):
        self.url = "wss://ws-feed.gdax.com/"
        self.products = ["LTC-USD"]
        self.message_count = 0
        print("Lets count the messages!")
    def on_message(self, msg):
        self.message_count += 1
        if 'price' in msg and 'type' in msg:
            print ("Message type:", msg["type"], 
                   "\t@ {}.3f".format(float(msg["price"])))
    def on_close(self):
        print("-- Goodbye! --")

wsClient = myWebsocketClient()
wsClient.start()
print(wsClient.url, wsClient.products)
while (wsClient.message_count < 500):
    print ("\nmessage_count =", "{} \n".format(wsClient.message_count))
    time.sleep(1)
wsClient.close()
```

The output is:

```
...
Message type: received  @ 50.78.3f
Message type: open      @ 50.78.3f
Message type: done      @ 51.56.3f
Message type: received  @ 51.59.3f
Message type: open      @ 51.59.3f
Message type: done      @ 51.51.3f
Message type: done      @ 51.17.3f
Message type: done      @ 51.66.3f

Kernel died, restarting
```

I have a few question regarding this code and output:

1. What does the message type (received, open, done, match) mean, which type is used for doing calculations, and why are some types skipped?
2. Why does running the code always ends in 'Kernel died, restarting'?
3. The documentation states that this code is for illustration only. Does that mean that this isn't a proper way of getting real-time data in order to do stuff with it?

If you know some good articles or books that can teach a noob how to work with WebSockets, I would love to hear about them!

Answer (score 1):

1) see the full documentation for each message [here](https://docs.gdax.com/#the-code-classprettyprintfullcode-channel)

2) Everything I find related to that issue stems from environment set up. Whether that is library dependencies not being properly installed or other environmental factors.

3) It's a proper way to set up a connection to the WebSocket but they don't provide any error handling or other logic. It's usually to cover themselves legally and reduce expectations for the code they provide (i.e. when someone receives error's similar to this they aren't liable to fix, update, help, etc)

Answer (score 0):

Python interpreter (3.6.2 64bit win) crashed on close() for me too.

Here is a fix (from https://github.com/danpaquin/gdax-python/issues/152):

```
client.stop = True
client.thread.join()
client.ws.close()
```

I just added these in the on_close method and no more crashes (so far).

ps: the issue linked say that it should be fixed in the latest gdax version but the latest pip gdax (1.0.6) still crashed.

Answer (score 0):

There are rather a few pitfalls to be aware of in building a full, real time order book (level 3) that I cannot document here but you may be interested to learn GDAX now offer a level 2 (almost real-time) update which will send you the updated prices for the order book. Probably much simpler to implement.